# How to update or delete data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a table to view records from database, i am unable to update or delete, nothing happens if I click on the buttons they are just redirected without the changes..what can be done to fix this.

update.php

```
<?php 

include 'includes/db.php';

//$student_id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['student_id'])) {
$student_id = $_REQUEST['student_id'];
}

if ( null==$student_id ) {
header("Location: addstudent.php");
}

if ( !empty($_POST)) {
// keep track valstudent_idation errors
$first_nameError = null;
$middle_nameError = null;
$last_nameError = null;
$emailError = null;
$idcodeError = null;

// keep track post values
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$middle_name = $_POST['middle_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$idcode = $_POST['idcode'];

// validate input
$valstudent_id = true;
if (empty($first_name)) {
$nameError = 'Please enter Name';
$valstudent_id = false;
}
$valstudent_id = true;
if (empty($middle_name)) {
$nameError = 'Please enter Name';
$valstudent_id = false;
}
$valstudent_id = true;
if (empty($last_name)) {
$nameError = 'Please enter Name';
$valstudent_id = false;
}

if (empty($email)) {
$emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
$valstudent_id = false;
} else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
$emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
$valstudent_id = false;
}

if (empty($idcode)) {
$idcodeError = 'Please enter IDCODE';
$valstudent_id = false;
}

// update data
if ($valstudent_id) {


 $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
 $middle_name=$_POST['middle_name'];
 $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $idcode=$_POST["idcode"];



 $sql = "UPDATE student SET first_name=:first_name, middle_name=:middle_name, last_name=:last_name, idcode=:idcode, email=:email WHERE student_id=:student_id";
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 //echo "<br/>Query: ".$stmt->query()."<br/>"

 $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
 $stmt->bindValue(':middle_name', $middle_name);
 $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
 $stmt->bindValue(':idcode', $idcode);
 $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

 $result= $stmt->execute();

 //$result = execute(array($first_name,middle_name,last_name,$email,$idcode));


header("Location: table.php");
}
}

 else {


$sql = "SELECT * FROM student where student_id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($student_id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$first_name = $data['first_name'];
$middle_name = $data['middle_name'];
$last_name = $data['last_name'];
$idcode = $data['idcode'];
$email = $data['email'];


}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">

 <div class="span10 offset1">
 <div class="row">
 <h3>Update People</h3>
 </div>

 <form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?student_id=<?php echo $student_id?>" method="post">
 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($first_nameError)?'error':'';?>">
 <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="first_Name" value="<?php echo !empty($first_name)?$first_name:'';?>">
 <?php if (!empty($first_nameError)): ?>
 <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $middle_nameError;?></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
 <label class="control-label">Middle Name</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input name="middle_name" type="text" placeholder="middle_Name" value="<?php echo !empty($middle_name)?$middle_name:'';?>">
 <?php if (!empty($middle_nameError)): ?>
 <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $middle_nameError;?></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
 <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="last_Name" value="<?php echo !empty($last_name)?$last_name:'';?>">
 <?php if (!empty($last_nameError)): ?>
 <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $lastnameError;?></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
 <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
 <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
 <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($idcodeError)?'error':'';?>">
 <label class="control-label">IDCODE</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input name="idcode" type="text" placeholder="IDCODE" value="<?php echo !empty($idcode)?$idcode:'';?>">
 <?php if (!empty($idcodeError)): ?>
 <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $idcodeError;?></span>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
 <a class="btn" href="table.php">Back</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>

 </div> <!-- /container -->
 </body>
</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(1);
include 'includes/db.php';
$student_id = 0;


if ( !empty($_GET['student_id'])) {
$student_id = $_REQUEST['student_id'];
}

if ( !empty($_POST)) {

$id = $_POST['student_id'];

// delete data


$sql = "DELETE FROM people WHERE student_id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($student_id));

header("Location: table.php");

} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">

 <div class="span10 offset1">
 <div class="row">
 <h3>Delete the Person</h3>
 </div>

 <form class="form-horizontal" action="delete.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id;?>"/>
 <p class="alert alert-error">Are you sure to delete ?</p>
 <div class="form-actions">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
 <a class="btn" href="table.php">No</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>

 </div> <!-- /container -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forget to bind `student_id` in update query

Comment: this is the error -"Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'"

Comment: @saty-thanks a lot that fixed the update